# Using Ionic Angular how to pass value from a service to a page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpclient

I am trying to use a service to retrieve data from the server and I need to pass the values to my Page from my service. I am not sure whether is this the appropriate way to achieve my requirement. Please help!.

**cart.service.ts**

```
export class CartService {

public jProducts="";

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
getMyProducts(){
const getValues = "http://website.com/temp.xq";

    this.http.get<any>(getValues, {responseType: 'text' as 'json'})
    .subscribe(
      (res:any) =>  console.log(this.jProducts = (res))      
      );
    return this.jProducts
    }
}
```

**mypage.ts**

```
import { CartService } from 'src/app/services/cart.service';
    loadValues: any= [];
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadValues = this.cartService.jrnProducts;
    }
```

Comment: what is `jrnProducts` ?? remove return keyword just add `this.http.get<any>(getValues, {responseType: 'text' as 'json'})
    .subscribe(
      (res:any) =>  this.jProducts = res;     
      );`

Comment: oops it is jProducts from service. Let me try your solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about importing HttpClientModule in @NgModule.

**CartService**

```
export class CartService {
    
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
        getProducts(): Observable<[]> { 
            const url = http://website.com/temp.xq;
    
            return this.http.get<any>(url); 
        };
    }
}
```

**CountrySearchComponent**

```
import { CartService } from 'src/app/services/cart.service';

export class CountrySearchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private destroy$ = new Subject();
    products: [] = [];

    constructor(private readonly cartService: CartService) {}
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.cartService.getProducts().pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
            tap(products: []) => this.products = products
        ).subscribe();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "mypage.ts" page there is a `ngOnInit()` function. Using this function you are trying to load the data from service. But I think the problem is that, you have to call the method inside your service from `ngOnInit()`. So, the code should look like inside your `ngOnInit()` should be `this.loadValues = this.cartService.getProducts();`.
 Here is a sample similar code link given On Stackblitz: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-data-service?file=app%2Fmy-data.service.ts)
 Please Check code in the link and let men know

Answer (score -1):

One of my simple example looks like this =>

**MovieService**

```
async attachMovie(id: string, params: Partial<IUserMovie>) {
   return this.http
     .post<IMovie>(`${this.apiUrl}/user/movies/${id}`, params, this.httpOptions)
     .pipe(
       catchError(this.handleError('Attach move to client'))
     )
     .toPromise();
 }
```

**MoviePage**

```
public movies: IMovie[] = [];

constructor(
  private movieService: MovieService,
) { }

async ngOnInit() {
  this.movies = await this.movieService
      .updateMovie(
         this.movie._id,
         {
           offset: video.currentTime,
           isWatched: video.ended
         }
   )
}
```

Or if you need you can use `subscription` instead `Promise`

I hope It'll help you! Be happy and Have a clean code :)